# Only int input recognized is 1

Tags: c++, do-while

No matter what I input, the only int recognized in this function is 1.
If anything else is selected, the do-while loop repeats.
The code also worked fine without any OR operators, e.g. *"while (input != 0)"*

```
void menu()
{
    int input = -1;
    do
    {
    cout << "         ---------------" << endl << "         -     OU6     -" << endl << "         ---------------" << endl;
    cout << "1. Read a transaction from the keyboard." << endl;
    cout << "2. Print all transactions to console." << endl;
    cout << "3. Calculate the total cost." << endl;
    cout << "4. Get debt of a single person." << endl;
    cout << "5. Get unreliable gold of a single person." << endl;
    cout << "6. List all persons and fix." << endl;
    cout << "0. Save and quit application." << endl;
    cin >> input;
    } while (input != (0 || 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6));

    if (input == 0)
    {
        cout << "0!" << endl;
        cin.get();
    }

    if (input == 1)
    {
        cout << "1!" << endl;
        cin.get();
    }

    if (input == 2)
    {
        cout << "2!" << endl;
        cin.get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This line:

```
while (input != (0 || 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6))
```

does not do what you think it does. You can't combine tests like this. What you have written is essentially equivalent to `while (input != true)`, and since `true` is equal to 1 you can see that the only option that will work is `input == 1`.

You need to change it to e.g.

```
while (input < 0 || input > 6)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing `input` to `0 || 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6`.

The result of `||` is a boolean, a truth value.

```
0 || 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6
```

is equivalent to

```
0 != 0 || 1 != 0 || 2 != 0 || 3 != 0 || 4 != 0 || 5 != 0 || 6 != 0
```

which is (hopefully obviously) true.

And a `bool` can be implicitly converted to an `int`, and `true` converts to `1`, so that's the reason for your only valid input; your condition is equivalent to `input != 1`.

The English phrase "If input is not 0 or 1" translated into logic is "If input is not 0 *and* input is not 1".

This would give you

```
while (input != 0 && input != 1 && input != 2 && input != 3 && input != 4 && input != 5 && input != 6)
```

which is a serious mess, and the more sensible thing to write is

```
while (input < 0 || input > 6)
```

or, more roundabout,

```
while (!(input >= 0 && input <= 6))
```

Comment: I prefer the extra detail about why the test does what it does.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, using || (logical OR) will make your condition equivalent to `(input != 1)`.

I suggest using a switch/case statement here and an additional condition:

```
void menu()
{
    int input = -1;
    bool inputIsValid = false ;
    do
    {
      cout << "         ---------------" << endl << "         -     OU6     -" << endl << "         ---------------" << endl;
      cout << "1. Read a transaction from the keyboard." << endl;
      cout << "2. Print all transactions to console." << endl;
      cout << "3. Calculate the total cost." << endl;
      cout << "4. Get debt of a single person." << endl;
      cout << "5. Get unreliable gold of a single person." << endl;
      cout << "6. List all persons and fix." << endl;
      cout << "0. Save and quit application." << endl;
      cin >> input;

      switch ( input ) 
      {
        case 0:
          cout << "0!" << endl;
          cin.get();
          inputIsValid = true;
        break;

        /* other cases here... */ 

        default:
          inputIsValid = false ;
        break;
      }
    } while ( false == inputIsValid ) ;
}
```